# How to remove row from Excel using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to delete row using the following code:

```
SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open( "test.xlsx", true );
IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where( s => s.Name == "sheet1" );

string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ( WorksheetPart )document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById( relationshipId );

IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>();

Row row = rows.FirstOrDefault<Row>();
row.Remove();

worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
document.Close();
```

But all I get is cleaning the first cell. I need to delete row with offset up other rows.
How can I do this?

Before
[image]
After
[image]

What I want to get:
[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f3ed5b4a-ab20-41be-8e5e-1f774b5e2f0e/how-to-delete-a-row-in-excel-file-with-open-xml-sdk?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1131824/How-can-I-delete-a-row-from-an-excel-file-using-Op#answer2

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yes there is(codeproject.com/Answers/1131824/) a solution, but it is done through some unthinkable crutches .. Is there no normal solution?

Comment: Well, since it seems to be tightly coupled with XML, I'm afraid so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

**Attention:**

**I do not have much experience, so the following code may not be effective**

```
        Row row = rows.FirstOrDefault<Row>();
        row.Remove();

        string cr;
        foreach ( Row rowElement in rows )
        {
            rowElement.RowIndex.Value -= 1;

            IEnumerable<Cell> cells = rowElement.Elements<Cell>().ToList();
            if ( cells != null )
            {
                foreach ( Cell cell in cells )
                {
                    cr = cell.CellReference.Value;

                    int indexRow = Convert.ToInt32( Regex.Replace( cr, @"[^\d]+", "" ) ) - 1;
                    cr = Regex.Replace( cr, @"[\d-]", "" );

                    cell.CellReference.Value = $"{cr}{indexRow}";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works only for 1st row, but not too hard to amend for any rows

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to removed empty rows

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pathToFile, true))
{
   WorkbookPart wbPart = document.WorkbookPart;

   var worksheet = wbPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet;
   var rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>();

   
   // Skip headers 
   foreach (var row in rows.Skip(1))
   {
      if (/* some condition on which rows to delete*/)
      {
         row.Remove();
      }
   }

   // Fix all row indexes
   string cr;
   for (int i = 2; i < rows.Count(); i++)
   {
      var newCurrentRowIndex = rows.ElementAt(i - 1).RowIndex.Value + 1;
      var currentRow = rows.ElementAt(i);

      currentRow.RowIndex.Value = updatedRowIndex;
      IEnumerable<Cell> cells = currentRow.Elements<Cell>().ToList();

      if (cells != null)
      {
         foreach (Cell cell in cells)
         {
            cr = cell.CellReference.Value;
            cr = Regex.Replace(cell.CellReference.Value, @"[\d-]", "");
            cell.CellReference.Value = $"{cr}{updatedRowIndex}";
         }
      }
   }

   worksheet.Save();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't say the logic you used  to find empty rows.